# Difference between ASCII comparison and string comparison

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I am using C#. When I am comparing two char value its sending me correct output, like,

```
'-'.CompareTo('!') //Its sending me positive value 12
```

means **'-' > '!'** is ***true***

But when I am comparing two string of same value its sending me different result

```
"-".CompareTo("!") //Its sending me negative value -1
```

means **"-" > "!"** is ***false***

Can anyone please explain me why it is doing so ? Should not it be 'true' for both cases ?

Comment: `CompareTo` is used for sorting, not (necessarily) for checking equality. Instances are considered "equal" if `CompareTo` returns zero. See [Char.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bhh2bx3h.aspx) and [String.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/35f0x18w.aspx) for further information.

Comment: From [Char.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bhh2bx3h.aspx) : The comparison performed by this method is based on the encoded values of this instance and *value*, not their lexicographical characteristics.

Comment: @Corak - I am implementing a binary search method for string. So I need a sorted array. So do you thing I should use CompareTo() or my own comparison method ?

Comment: @Arnab be careful to do custom string comparison unless you're really aware of difference between cultures (or you work with a single culture). Character comparison (as you can see) it's pretty misleading.

Comment: "Depends"... In any case, you probably don't want the `char` logic when comparing `strings`. The question is how *do* you want them sorted. Should it be culture aware, or culture independent, or lexicographically independent? Does `String.CompareTo` or `String.CompareToOrdinal` sort like you want? Then use those, otherwise build your own sorting logic. -- you might also want to take a look at [Compare with StringComparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e6883c06.aspx) and [Compare with CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc190529.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

String's Compare method is culture specific. That's why you get different results. use `string.CompareOrdinal` instead, which is byte by byte comparison.

```
var v = '-'.CompareTo('!');//12
var s = string.CompareOrdinal("-", "!");//12
```

[Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I am implementing a binary search method for string. So I need a sorted array. So do you thing using CompareTo() will be any problem or should I use CompareOrdinal ?

Comment: That depends on how your results needs to be, If you need culture dependent comparison use  `CompareTo`, There are other options to compare, they are `InvariantCulture` and ignore case variants of them. Refer to the link I provided and choose your best fit.

Answer (score 4):

This comparison `'-'.CompareTo('!')` will perform an **ordinal comparison**. It'll compare numeric UTF-16 encoded values (`45` and `33`).

String comparison `"-".CompareTo("!")` is different and it'll perform a **culture aware comparison**. It means that, no matters the numeric value, characters will be ordered according to **sorting rules for current culture**.

You can try yourself using ordinal comparison for strings:

```
String.CompareOrdinal("-", "!")
```

That will perform an ordinal comparison on strings and then you'll get same result (`12`).

You can't perform a (true) culture aware comparison on `Char` (in case you need it simply convert to `string`) because sorting order may be affected by characters before and/or after what you're comparing, single character may not be a grapheme (and ordering may not apply). One example: in Czech language <kbd>C</kbd> comes before <kbd>H</kbd> then you expect `"ch".CompareTo("h") == -1`...wrong, "ch" is a *digraph* and it's between <kbd>H</kbd> and <kbd>I</kbd> then `"ch".CompareTo("h") == 1`!!! More on this on [this more detailed post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27229590/1207195).

Ordinal comparison is different simply because of heritage from ASCII (every culture I tried returned same result for that ordering). They preserved ASCII ordering for compatibility (and easier migration to Unicode) but for string comparison they must respect culture rules.

A more common example of this is with upper-case/lower-case characters (note <kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd> to perform ordinal and culture-aware comparison):

```
'A'.CompareTo('a') != "A".CompareTo("a")
```

If you're doing this to perform a text search then I strongly suggest you **do not use `Char` comparison directly** unless you're aware of culture issues (ordering) and Unicode details (surrogates and encoding, primary).

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a difference in implementation of `IComparable` method `CompareTo` in `Char` and `String` classes

> Char.cs

```
public int CompareTo(Char value) {
      return (m_value-value);
}
```

> String.cs

```
public int CompareTo(String strB) {
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(this, strB, 0);
}
```

where logic is culture-aware comparison which rely in the internal `InternalCompareString`.